# Average function in macro not returning value

Tags: vba, excel, average, worksheet-function

```
Dim XXXX as string

XXXX = Sheets("Sheet1").Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("J7:J607")).value
Sheets("Log").Cells(2, "Z").value = XXXX

End Function
```

Please see the above macro. I need the average of the values available in J column and need to paste that average value in "Log" sheet. But the value is not returning, instead leaving it as a blank cell. But the code runs fine, not showing any error.

Please help me to fix this issue guys.

Comment: Why is XXXX a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following would work in place of your current code:

```
Dim XXXX As String

XXXX = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("J7:J607"))
Sheets("Log").Cells(2, "Z").Value = XXXX
```

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that but just assumed the user was wrapping the code in a Function (which I notice lots of people seem to do..) instead of a Sub.

Comment: Why not just `Sheets("Log").Cells(2, "Z").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("J7:J607"))`? Force the format of the cell to `Text` if it is that important.

Comment: @AJD, Of course, if the value isn't needed for anything else then directly writing it to the cell is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write to another cell in a `Function` and then I am guessing that you are calling that from a worksheet?

Use a `Sub` instead. Of Course you cant call this from a worksheet.

Try this

```
Private Sub Sample()
    Dim XXXX As String

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        XXXX = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(.Range("J7:J607"))
        Sheets("Log").Cells(2, "Z").Value = XXXX
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to use a function and call it from a worksheet then use it like this

```
Private Function GetAvg()
    GetAvg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J7:J607"))
End Function
```

and then in cell `Z2` Type this

```
=GetAvg()
```